# How to get parent node from a attachment in drupal8 search api results

Tags: 8, search

I have apachesolr index search with Search API attachments. In the results I get a link to the file but I would like to get a link to the parent node. I tried in the view but there is no such field with relationship to file usage.
I wrote the following in a module to override the field fid in the view but it returns an error

```
function hook_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
$view = $variables['view'];
$field = $variables['field'];
    if ($view->storage->id() == 'saa' &&
    $view->current_display == 'page_1' &&
    $field->field == 'fid') {
        $fid =  $variables['output']; 
        $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
        $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
        $variables['results'] = $file_usage;
    }
}
```

It returns

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\file\FileUsage\DatabaseFileUsageBackend::listUsage() must implement interface Drupal\file\FileInterface, null given, called in /home/rebecca/public_html/new5/modules/pdf_app/pdf_app.module on line 262 in Drupal\file\FileUsage\DatabaseFileUsageBackend->listUsage() (line 123 of core/modules/file/src/FileUsage/DatabaseFileUsageBackend.php).

Comment: the pdf_app is a custom module ?

Comment: yes it is a custom module

Comment: So add the line 262 of `modules/pdf_app/pdf_app.module` or take a look at this line to see the issue

Comment: line 262 is in the code it is $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);

Comment: `$file` should be instance of `Drupal\file\FileInterface` but in this case `$file` is null 
so you should check first on `$file`  something like `if ($file && $file instanceof Drupal\file\FileInterface) {
    $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
  }`

Comment: now I am getting Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (line 266 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple(Array) (Line: 250)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load(Object) (Line: 532)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase::load(Object) (Line: 261)
pdf_app_preprocess_views_view_field(Array, 'views_view_field__fid', Array) (Line: 287)

Comment: all logic use `$file` and `$file_usage`  should be inside the if condition

Comment: that is like this $field = $variables['field'];
     if ($view->storage->id() == 'saa' &&
    $view->current_display == 'page_1' && $field->field == 'fid') {
     $fid =  $variables['output']; 
     $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
     if ($file && $file instanceof Drupal\file\FileInterface) { 
    $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
         $variables['results'] = $file_usage;
        }

Comment: try with what i post in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help I got I manage to get it working

```
function hook_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
 $view = $variables['view'];
$field = $variables['field'];
if ($view->storage->id() == 'saa' &&
$view->current_display == 'page_1' &&
$field->field == 'fid') {
$fid = $variables['output']; 
if (!is_string($fid)){ 
$fid = $variables['output']->__toString();
}

$file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
if ($file && $file instanceof Drupal\file\FileInterface) {
  $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
  //var_dump($file_usage);
 if (array_key_exists("node",$file_usage['file'])){
  $essai = $file_usage['file']['node'];
}
 elseif (array_key_exists("media",$file_usage['file'])){
$essai = $file_usage['file']['media'];
}
  $news = (array_keys($essai));
  $new2 = (array_values($news));
  $nef = array_values($new2)[0];
  $event = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nef);
if (!$event)
 return false;

// add ->toString() or other if needed
$abs_link = $event->toLink(NULL, 'canonical', ['absolute' => true]);
  $variables['output'] = $abs_link;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$file` should be instance of `Drupal\file\FileInterface` but in this case `$file` is null so you should check first on `$file` something

```
function hook_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];
  if ($view->storage->id() == 'saa' &&
    $view->current_display == 'page_1' &&
    $field->field == 'fid') {
    $fid = $variables['output']->__toString();
    $file = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($fid);
    if ($file && $file instanceof Drupal\file\FileInterface) {
      $file_usage = \Drupal::service('file.usage')->listUsage($file);
      $variables['output'] = $file_usage;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still getting Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (line 266 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple(Array) (Line: 250)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load(Object) (Line: 532)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase::load(Object) (Line: 261)
pdf_app_preprocess_views_view_field(Array, 'views_view_field__fid', Array) (Line: 287) and no link to the node is showing...

Comment: check the `$fid` value `var_dump($fid);` for example

Comment: I am getting object(Drupal\Core\Render\Markup)#4062 (1) { ["string":protected]=> string(2) "24" } object(Drupal\Core\Render\Markup)#4118 (1) { ["string":protected]=> string(2) "41" }} The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by   but if i write $variables['output'] = $fid; it gives me the id of the file

Comment: ok try to dump var_dump($fid->__toString());

Comment: I am getting The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'var_dump' (T_STRING) in Drupal\Core\Extension\Extension->load() (line 262 of modules/pdf_app/pdf_app.module). but if i replace $fid with the id of the field i still get the original error

Comment: and this `var_dump($variables['output']->__toString());`

Comment: You should get the fid as number for example 24 or 41 not the markup

Comment: I got string(2) "24" string(2) "41" string(2) "12" string(2) "20" string(2) "34" string(1) "3" string(1) "4" The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/home/rebecca/public_html/new5/modules/pdf_app/pdf_app.module" at line 263. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 145 of vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php).

Comment: now i get User error: "6" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

Comment: Ok test with my updated answer, it will work !

Comment: Test now `$variables['results']` hold result of the view so if you change it to number will not work or use `$variables['output']` instead , test with my last update

Comment: Test my last update

Comment: still getting User error: "6" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children(Array, 1) (Line: 402)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array) (Line: 444)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, ) (Line: 200)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array) (Line: 501)..

Comment: thank you so much for all your help I managed to find the solution.